# MVC4 site and CNAME - only showing @RenderBody content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I just deployed my MVC4-.Net4.0 website to http://regatta.azurewebsites.net/ 
This works nicely - the jQuery and jQueryMobile scripts renders this perfectly.

I then followed the instructions and added my own domain - http://regatta.albrektsen.net and configured my dns supplier with both a CNAME and an A record pointing to azure.

This again works fine - I get to http://regatta.albrektsen.net - and the site comes up.
However: When accessing my custom domain, I only get the stuff rendered by `@RenderBody()`

Basically the

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/mobileCss", "~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" @TempData["DataUrl"]>
        <div data-role="header">
            @if (IsSectionDefined("Header")) {
                @RenderSection("Header")
            } else {
                @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home");
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            }
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is missing when accessing my custom domain - only the stuff displayed by @RenderBody is shown.

How is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks fine to me, did you already fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops - embarassing...

Actually - this turned out to be a problem with my PC's DNS cache.

Issuing ipconfig /flushdns (With admin privileges) solved the issue. My "local" regatta.albrektsen.net was pointing to a test server.